# Циклический сдвиг массива

Tags: массивы, c

Например, нужно осуществить циклический сдвиг вправо на n элементов. А как осуществить циклический сдвиг вправо на -n элементов? Каким получится массив?

Напишите просто какой правильный ответ:
Массив - 1 2 3 4 5
Сдвинуть вправо на -2 (отрицательное число)

Правильным будет ответ `3 4 5 1 2` или `3 4 5 2 1` ?

Comment: Циклический сдвиг вправо на -n элементов? Это же циклический сдвиг влево, но на n элементов!

Comment: Правильный ответ 3 4 5 1 2

Answer (score 15):

Правильным будет ответ  3 4 5 1 2

**update**

Циклический сдвиг вправо на -2 это то же самое, что и циклический сдвиг влево на 2.

Есть удивительный по своей простоте алгоритм из трех `reverse(array, size)` для циклического сдвига влево, который легко запомнить и в реализации которого практически невозможно ошибиться.

Вот как он работает с `12345` (s[] = 12345, size = 5, dist = 2)

```
reverse(s, dist);               // 21|345
reverse(s + dist, size - dist); // 21|543
reverse(s, size);               // 34512
```

[Пишут](http://codelab.ru/task/cycle_shift/), что Кен Томпсон (Ken Thompson) написал редактор с функцией 
reverse в 1971 году, и он утверждает, что она уже тогда была легендарной.

P.S.
так случилось, что я недавно сравнил производительность этого алгоритма, со [сдвигом перестановкой блоков](http://codelab.ru/task/cycle_shift/) (который в среднем требует меньше пересылок элементов массива и им я пользовался раньше) и с удивлением обнаружил, что алгоритм на `reverse()`, несмотря на большее количество операций с памятью, даже чуть быстрее.
Вот и решил поделиться.

Answer (score 9):

В большинстве языков наверняка это уже реализовано. Например, в C++ это `std::rotate` из `<algorithm>`

```
std::rotate(&a[first], &a[middle], &a[last]);
```

После этого происходит циклический сдвиг, так что middle становится первым элементом. Касательно сдвига вправо, влево: в силу цикличности сдвиг вправо на n элементов, это сдвиг влево на m - n элементов, где m - размер массива.

Если вам нужно написать на C (учебное задание, я так понимаю?), то в качестве образца можно взять ту же реализацию из STL

```
ForwardIterator next = middle;
while (first != next)
{
    swap (*first++, *next++);
    if (next == last)
        next = middle;
    else if (first == middle) 
        middle = next;
}
```

Огрубляя, идея работы такая (сдвиг влево на 1):

```
1234
2134
2314
2341
```

Comment: Мне нужно свою функцию написать на Си, а не пользоваться встроенными

Comment: Надо было тогда сразу указывать, что вам нужно написать функцию на Си

Answer (score 5):

```
    int[] a = new int[]{236, 267, 973, 357};
    int n = 1;
    int[] b = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(i+n >= a.length){
            b[i+n-a.length] = a[i];
        }
        else{
            b[i+n] = a[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i : b) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

На выходе в консоле вы получите сдвиг вправо на n (на 1).

P.S. Не уверен, что конструкция из первой строки существует в С, ибо пишу на Java, однако основная идея должна быть понятна. И вывод результата тоже другой)

Answer (score 4):

Дам пример под C#.
Не знаю понятней или нет, я обычно пишу вот так. Метод можно оформить как расширение. При shiftValue положительном сдвиг происходит в право, при отрицательном влево.

```
public static T[] Shift<T>(T[] array, int shiftValue)
{       
    var newArray = new T[array.Length];
    shiftValue -= array.Length;
    if(shiftValue < 0)
    {
        shiftValue*=-1;
    }


    for(var i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
    {
        var index = (i + shiftValue) % array.Length;

        newArray[i] = array[index]; 
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Набирал с тела, но вроде так

вправо

```
for (I = 1; I <= n; I++)
{ 
    b = [10];
    for (j = 10; j <= 0; j = j - 1)
        a[j]=[j-1];
    a[1] = b;
}
```

влево

```
for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) 
{
    int first = a[1];
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    a[i] = a[i + 1];
    a[10] = first;
}
```

Comment: n - отрицательное число

Comment: оу, ответил про сдвиг вправо... извиняюсь, щас исправим;)

Answer (score -2):

У меня так работает.

```
void array_Rotate_Right(unsigned char*p,unsigned char e){    
    unsigned char i,i1;    
    for (i1=0;i1<e;i1++){    
        for(i = 6; i>0; i--){    
            p[i]>>=1;    
            if((p[i-1]&0x1)==0x1) p[i]+=128;    
        }    
    p[0]>>=1;    
    }    
}
```

Comment: минус. Не вижу какое отношение приведённый код имеет к вопросу. Приведите полный пример (с main()), который из `1 2 3 4 5` массива и `-2` (отрицательное число) получает `3 4 5 1 2` массив.

Answer (score -5):

Не знаю на каком языке вы хотели, я напишу на С++, получится как-то так

```
for (int i = /*сюда число, какой длины массив*/; i >= 0; i--)
{
    a[i+n] = a[i];
}
```

Comment: Однозначно не вижу rotate (циклического сдвига) !!!

То же и в следующем ответе (@Leshij_2005), хотя там проклевывается здравая мысль о сохранении элемента массива.

Comment: Согласен, это не rotare, а shift, причем один из элементов теряется насовсем, а с другого конца получается мусор.

Comment: Это самый логичный вариант сдвига, вместо того чтобы сохранять первый и т.д. я сразу перевернес на +н шагов вперед, может неправильно понял задачу, нужно лучше обьяснять а не ставить минусы...

Comment: Да, @arman_pap, Вы неправильно поняли задачу. 

Требуется **циклической** сдвиг. Например при циклическом сдвиге на 1 вправо [1 2 3] перейдет в [3 1 2], т.е. последний элемент массива попадет в первую (индекс 0) позицию. 

Кстати, в вопросе это учитывается, автор вопроса просто почему-то запутался с порядком переходящих из начала в конец массива элементов.