# Проблема с задачей,новичок не могу понять где ошибки на языке си

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм

Преобразовать матрицу так, чтобы строка с номером l непосредственно располагалась за строкой с номером k с сохранением порядка следования остальных строк.

```c
void Zadacha(
  short m //Число строк
  n, //Число столбцов
  float a[SIZE][SIZE], //Исходная Матрица
  int k // Первое целое значение
  l
) { //Второе целое значение
  // Объявления и комментарии локальных переменных                   
  short i,
  j,
  float tmp,
  for (j = 0, j < a, j++) {
    tmp = a[l][j];

    for (i = l, k > i, k != i, k++) {
      a[l][j] = a[l - 1][j];
      a[k + 1][j] = tmp;

      for (i = l, k < i, k != i, k--) {
        a[l][j] = a[l + 1][j];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ошибки

> expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'void' void  Zadacha

Comment: astyle просто растерялся, форматируя *ЭТО*... :)

Comment: Для начала переставьте первую открывающую фигурную скобочку (за первую закрывающую круглую)

Comment: Затем добавьте `main()` (если, конечно, его где-то в полной версии еще нет) и почитайте [вот этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/32205/232) и ответы к нему.

Comment: есть шаблонная версия main,но как добавил одна осталась

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прямолинейный подход к решению задания может выглядеть следующим образом, как это показано ниже в демонстрационной программе

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5

void move_row(int a[SIZE][SIZE], size_t source, size_t target)
{
    if (source < SIZE && target < SIZE)
    {
        if (source < target)
        {
            for (; source < target; ++source)
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                {
                    int tmp = a[source][i];
                    a[source][i] = a[source + 1][i];
                    a[source + 1][i] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        else if ( target + 1 < source)
        {
            for (; target + 1 < source; --source)
            {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                {
                    int tmp = a[source][i];
                    a[source][i] = a[source - 1][i];
                    a[source - 1][i] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //  There is nothing to do.
        }
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[SIZE][SIZE] =
    {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 },
        { 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 },
        { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 }
    };


    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    move_row(a, 0, 3);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    move_row(a, 3, 0);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
 0  0  0  0  0
 1  1  1  1  1
 2  2  2  2  2
 3  3  3  3  3
 4  4  4  4  4

 1  1  1  1  1
 2  2  2  2  2
 3  3  3  3  3
 0  0  0  0  0
 4  4  4  4  4

 1  1  1  1  1
 0  0  0  0  0
 2  2  2  2  2
 3  3  3  3  3
 4  4  4  4  4
```

Тип элементов массива может быть любой. Если вам нужен тип `float`, то вы должны изменить объявление массива как

```
float a[SIZE][SIZE] = { /*...*/ };
```

Соответственно и функции везде надо заменить тип `int` на тип `float`, а также надо будет использовать правильный символ форматирования при использовании функции `printf`.

Comment: Vlad from Moscow можно вопрос,а что такое source,по крайней мере не пользовался им вот и не знаю

Comment: @Shamchik Это имя параметра функции. Вы можете назвать его  как хотите. Он означает индекс исходной строки, которую надо перенести, а target - индекс строки, после которой нужно переместить исходную строку. Эти имена соответствуют вашим именам I и k. Просто мне так было удобнее их назвать.

Comment: Vlad from Moscow он на С++?

Comment: @Shamchik Здесь нет ничего специфического от C++. Программа должна компилироваться как C программа.

Comment: Vlad from Moscow понял вас. спасибо,по разбираю  ее

Comment: Vlad from Moscow еще вопрос size t i,j это как я понял размер строчек и столбов идет?

Comment: @Shamchik Это индексы, соответственно, по строкам и по столбцам.