# Символьный массив

Tags: c++

**Задание:**
Вывести слова введенного текста, изменив каждое слово следующим образом: буквы слова, стоящие до первой гласной, перенести в конец слова. Использовать можно только символьные массивы, string нельзя.

---

Смог это реализовать используя `string temp`, а string нельзя использовать. Никак не могу решить данную задачу без использования вышеупомянутого типа. =(

Так же из-за проблем с кодировкой, писал под английский.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

bool glasn(char a){
    //ёеуыаоэяиюЁУЕЫАОЭЯИЮ //"eyuioaEYUIOA"
    char g[12] = { 'e', 'y',  'u',  'i',  'o',  'a',  'E',  'Y',  'U',  'I',  'O', 'A' };
    for(int i = 0; i<18; i++){
        if(a == g[i])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(){
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    cout << "Text: " << endl;
    char* s = new char;
    cin.getline(s, 256, '\n');
    string temp = "";
    bool done = true;
    for(int i = 0; i<int(strlen(s)); i++){
        if(!glasn(s[i]) and s[i] != ' ' and done)
            temp += s[i];
        else if(glasn(s[i]))
        {
            done = false;
            cout << s[i];
        }
        else if(s[i] == ' '){
            cout << temp << " ";
            done = true;
            temp = {};
        }
        if(!done and !glasn(s[i]))
            cout << s[i];
        //cout << "(" << done << ")";
    }
    cout << temp;
    //cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" << temp;
}
```

Comment: Для однобайтной кодировки (все ascii символы  в utf-8 тоже занимают 1 байт) это можно сделать по месту,  вращением элементов массива, которые занимает слово. Т.е. находите начало слова, его конец и первую гласную. Затем вращате влево на количество символов до гласной. Метод вращения описан [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/32249/232)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно всего лишь выводить, так что можно так:

```
char* s = new char[256];
cin.getline(s, 256, '\n');
char g[] = "eyuioaEYUIOA";
// находим позицию первой гласной буквы
int n = strcspn(s, g);  
cout << s + n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    cout << s[i];
```